# Dokan cAlternateFileName doesn't seem to work

Tags: filesystems, dokan

I am writing a File System Driver for Windows 7. I'm using the Dokan library. In the FindFiles function I want to set the 8.3 alternate name. I am assuming that will show up if I use dir /x but it doesn't. I have tried passing a null terminated string then changed to a blank padded (not null terminated) string as coded below. Neither one show the alternate name the dir /x.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for a reference to cAlternateFileName in struct _WIN32_FIND_DATA.

Does anyone have any information on this?

Here is a clip from my code:

```
        wsprintf(w_surfaceName, L"S%d-P%02x~1", pCartIDtable[count].dsmNumber, pCartIDtable[count].pltrNumber);
        wp = wcschr(w_surfaceName, L'\0');
        wmemset(wp, L' ', _countof(w_surfaceName) - (wp - w_surfaceName));
        wmemcpy(findData.cAlternateFileName, w_surfaceName, _countof(findData.cAlternateFileName));
        FillFindData(&findData, DokanFileInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either the file doesn't have an 8.3 short-name, or the field hasn't been filled in.

Some versions of Windows have short-name generation turned off by default. Some people have short-name generation turned of just to make the file system faster. Even if you have short-name generation turned on now, that doesn't retro-actively go and generate short names across your existing file system.

And the field is not filled in anyway if the request was only for "FindExInfoBasic".

Answer (score 0):

Dokan does not support 8.3 short-names at this point. Progress for implementation of this feature is tracked at:  https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/issues/301